# Getting HTML syntax translated to work in XML, works perfectly in html but not in XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, csc

I am working on a project and have run across an issue that I have been unable to find a clear answer to. I am using OUCampus which has XML as its syntax, unfortunately I can not change this. I do not understand what to change to make this work in XML. I have tried looking into the proper syntax of "converting" JavaScript to work within XML but none of the suggestions have worked. From the looks of the error which is overlapping images and a broken repeat the line from a part of the code being ignored by the XML compiler syntax or at least that is why my friend and I are seeing and guessing is happening. Does anyone have suggestions on how to get this working properly in XML syntax? I do not understand XML enough to fix this, I am more rooted in HTML and therefore am lost. My friend and I are attempting to make an image scroller with the below specifications and this is what we have which is not quite working properly.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Image Scroller</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #scroller {
        position: relative;
    }
    #scroller .innerScrollArea {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #scroller ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
   #scroller li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: absolute;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="scroller" style="width: 1000px; height: 75px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="innerScrollArea">
        <style> img {padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px;}</style>
        <ul>
            <!-- Define photos here -->
            <li><a href="https://www.l3t.com/"><img class="first" src="{{f:21250202}}" width="125" height="75"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html"><img src="{{f:21250199}}" width="75" height="75"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.conservice.com/"><img src="{{f:21250197}}" width="266" height="75"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ramcompany.com/wordpress/"><img src="{{f:21250201}}" width="150" height="75"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.imflash.com/"><img src="{{f:21250195}}" width="236" height="75"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.tecuity.com/"><img src="{{f:21250200}}" width="186" height="75"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.vivint.com/"><img src="{{f:21250196}}" width="256" height="75"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://state.nationalguard.com/utah"><img src="{{f:21250198}}" width="92" height="75"/></a></li>
           </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 <!-- XML does not recognize javascript. have to use something to fix this-->
 $(function(){
        var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
        var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
        scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
        var curX = 0;
        scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css('left', curX);
            curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
        });
        var fullW = curX / 2;
        var viewportW = scroller.width();

        // Scrolling speed management
        var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:1.75};
        var $controller = $(controller);
        var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
        {
            if (duration === undefined)
                duration = 600;
            $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
        };

        // Pause on hover
        scroller.hover(function(){
            tweenToNewSpeed(0);
        }, function(){
            tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
        });

        // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
        var doScroll = function()
        {
            var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
            var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
            if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
                newX -= fullW;
            scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
        };
        setInterval(doScroll, 20);
        tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping the javacript in a CDATA section?

Comment: I do not what that is, could you please explain more? @duffmo

Comment: Maybe move the javascript code into a .js file and [include it](https://webfirst.uark.edu/how-to-link-to-javascript-files/)?